# How to detect an event and ensure its the first (earliest event that occurred?

Tags: sql

I am attempting to extract data from a large patient database using SQL. I need to detect when an event occurred. In this case, it will be a decrease in SpO2 by 10% from when treatment started. It needs to be the earliest time point when it decreased. Example 100%-95-92-97-88-92-89 only the 88 is what I will need. The tricky part begins as patients might have two treatments throughout care. I need to compare these treatments to observe which treatment is the best. An example of the data is below.
The patient will have treatment A until treatment B starts or until the final reading and vis versa. the SpO2 values with ** are the ones I need to extract

| Date | Time | SpO2 | Treatment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/19/22 | 18:23 | 100 | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:24 | 95 | A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:25 | 90 | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:26 | **85** | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:27 | N/A | B |
| 05/19/22 | 18:27 | 90 | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:28 | 85 | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:29 | **80** | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:30 | 78 | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:31 | 76 | N/A |

What I'm hoping the final table looks like is

| Date | Time | SpO2 | Treatment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05/19/22 | 18:23 | 100 | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:24 | 95 | A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:26 | **85** | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:27 | N/A | B |
| 05/19/22 | 18:27 | 90 | N/A |
| 05/19/22 | 18:29 | **80** | N/A |

If you can please help, that would be amazing and thank you very much.

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: I dont know SQL at all. My best attempt is 

Select * from <table name> t 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT patient_id, max(spo2) as max_spo2 
FROM <table name> GROUP BY patient_id) p 
ON t.patient_id ==p.patient_id 
WHERE spo2 < max_spo2*0.9 N nj

However, this only selects values below the max SpO2 value and doesn't account for the treatment section. any help is appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.